# Standard deviation of POSIXlt type variable

Tags: r

How can I calculate the standard deviation from POSIXlt type variable?
I got the min and max from `summary`  but there is no standard deviation. I try `sd(dd)` and I get inexplicable number: `242.5095`

My data:

```
str(dd)
POSIXlt[1:71]
  format: "2015-10-01 00:03:43" "2015-10-01 00:01:06" "2015-10-01 00:01:17" "2015-10-01 00:00:41" ...

summary(dd)
                 Min.               1st Qu.                Median                  Mean               3rd Qu. 
"2015-10-01 00:00:26" "2015-10-01 00:01:00" "2015-10-01 00:01:19" "2015-10-01 00:03:02" "2015-10-01 00:03:15" 
                 Max. 
"2015-10-01 00:26:08"
```

Comment: Please `dput(dd)`. But I guess your value is in seconds.

Comment: if you can explain a little ? I do not have enough experience in R

Comment: It isn't really fair to say that `242.5059` is inexplicable.  It just doesn't conform to what you expected.  The first relevant question I would ask is, what exactly does the standard deviation of a date/time object represent?  What are you intending to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `dplyr` for this:

```
dd = data.frame(t = Sys.time() + 1:100)
dd %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, min, max, as.numeric(sd(.))))
                 mean                 min                 max as.numeric
1 2015-10-01 11:40:25 2015-10-01 11:39:35 2015-10-01 11:41:14   29.01149
```

Note that I cast the `sd` first to `numeric` in order to get a numeric value. Also note that I use `POSIXct` and not `POSIXlt`.

Answer (score 0):

The standard deviation you get is in seconds.

`sd` takes a numeric vector, or converts the input to numeric. `as.numeric` calls `as.double` internally which gives the seconds since the epoc for `POSIXlt` objects.